# durandal 3rd level child router

Tags: durandal, durandal-navigation

Once I declare 3rd level router, I am facing problem in navigation between modules defined in 2nd level router.
The issue is: when I navigate in between different modules at 2nd level router, activate is fired but attached is not fired for the module.

Code snippet for routers is as follow:

```
//1st level router
landing.router = router.map([
{ route: 'resourcebrowser*splat', title: 'Resource', moduleId: 'viewmodels/resourcebrowser', nav: true },
]).buildNavigationModel();

//2nd level router
var childRouter = parentView.router = landing.router.createChildRouter()
.makeRelative({
moduleId: 'viewmodels/tab/',
fromParent: true
}).map([
{ route: ':id/details', moduleId: 'details', title: 'Details', type: 'intro', nav: true },
{ route: ':id/docs*splat', moduleId: 'documents', title: 'Documents', type: 'intro', nav: true }
]).buildNavigationModel();

//3rd level router

var childRouter = parentView.router.createChildRouter()
.makeRelative({
moduleId: 'viewmodels/viewer/',
route: ':id/docs/'
})
.map([
{ route: 'documentviewer/:docid', moduleId: 'documentviewer', title: 'Viewer', type: 'intro', nav: true }
]).buildNavigationModel();
```

Kindly let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for `canReuseForRoute` : http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html

If you define the `canReuseForRoute` function and return `false`, I believe you will find that 2nd level router viewmodel is recreated completely as you intend.